# Source Maps not found in VS Code because of embedded path

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, visual-studio-code, source-maps

I have an angular app that is built using gulp. As with most Angular apps, the code is written in TypeScript and then compiled to Javascript.
The generated Javascript file is located besides the TypeScript file. The source map file is also located in the same folder.
When I open the console in Chrome and navigate to one of the Javascript files, Chrome tells me that it was able to detect source maps.
When I am trying to debug the app from within VS Code it is tells me:

> Unverified breakpoint, Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)

Now, I did some digging and the source map contains this header:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["app/lib/_common/equipment/components/equipment-selection/equipmentSelection.component.ts"]
```

The source map file contains no `sourceRoot`.
If I edit the source map and remove the path and just leave the file name, VS Code can load the source map and debugging works correctly:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["equipmentSelection.component.ts"]
```

What do I need to change in my config to generate the correct source maps?

The relevant part of the `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('typescript', ['lint'], () => {

    let sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
        ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
        merge = require('merge2');

    let tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

    let tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({}))
        .pipe(precompileNgx())
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .on('error', function () {
            gutil.log(gutil.colors.red("*** THERE IS AN ERROR IN YOUR TYPESCRIPT FILES ***"));
            gutil.log(gutil.colors.red("The code will not compile until this is fixed!"));
        });

    return merge([
        tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('./' + libPath)),
        tsResult.js.pipe(sourcemaps.write(".", {includeContent: true}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    ]);
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.4.2",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "./",
        "sourceRoot": "./app/",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noEmitHelpers": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": false,
        //"importHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "build",
        "node_modules",
        "app/jspm_packages"
    ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\app"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You need to get your rootDir back, or advance the amount of levels you need.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "../../../../../../",
```

You need to do this considering the index of your project.
In my case I did taking into account my index, it was like this:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["index.ts"],... "sourceRoot":"../../../src"}
```

I hope it helps.